# C++ switch-like code structure

Tags: c++, object-oriented

I'm developing a class for connection to LCD (Liquid Crystal Display).
It can connect in two modes: 4-bit and 8-bit. And the number of modes may be increased. The mode can be configured in the constructor.
A lot of behavior depends on the mode. But! The mode can be changed in run-time, so I can't create the `Lcd` abstract class and two derivatives `FourBitLcd` and `EightBitLcd`.
Code:

```
class Lcd {
public:
    enum Mode {
        Mode4bit,
        Mode8bit,
    };

    explicit Lcd(Mode mode) : mode(mode) {}

public:
    void Init() {
        if (this->mode == Mode8bit) {
            SendCommand(LCD_CMD_8_BIT_MODE);
        }
        else {
            this->Reset();
            SendCommand(LCD_CMD_4_BIT_MODE);
        }
    }

    void SendCommand(uint8_t command_id) {
        
        if (this->mode == Mode8bit) {
            this->SendLowerNibble(command_id);
        }
        else {
            this->SendHigherNibble(command_id);
            this->SendCmdSignals();
            command_id <<= 4;
        }

        this->SendHigherNibble(command_id);
        this->SendCmdSignals();
    }

    void SendData(uint8_t data) {

        if (this->mode == Mode8bit) {
            this->SendLowerNibble(data);
        }
        else {
            this->SendHigherNibble(data);
            this->SendDataSignals();
            data <<= 4;
        }

        this->SendHigherNibble(data);
        this->SendDataSignals();
    }

private:
    
    void BusyCheck() {
        // ...
        
        if (this->mode == Mode4bit) {
            en.Write(true);
            _delay_us(10);
            en.Write(false);
            _delay_us(10);
        }
        
        // ...
    }
    
    void Reset();
    void SendHigherNibble(uint8_t val);
    void SendLowerNibble(uint8_t val);
    void SendCmdSignals();
    void SendDataSignals();

private:
    Mode mode = Mode8bit;
};
```

In this case, I think I should use polymorphism instead of if/else. But then I have another problem. For example, I can create `ModeStrategy` abstract class and `FourBitModeStrategy` and `EightBitModeStrategy`. But derivative classes need the instance of the class `Lcd` because they need to use its methods such as `SendLowerNibble` and `SendHigherNibble`. But if I pass a pointer of `Lcd` to derivatives of `ModeStrategy` then it will be a bidirectional reference. As far as I know, it's not good. For example, code:

```
class Lcd {
public:
    class ModeStrategy {
    public:
        void InitLcdPtr(Lcd *lcd) {
            this->lcd_ = lcd;
        }

        virtual void InitMode() = 0;

        virtual void SendCommandPart(uint8_t &command_id) = 0;

        virtual void SendDataPart(uint8_t &data) = 0;

        virtual void BusyCheck() {}

    protected:
        Lcd *lcd_ = nullptr;
    };

    class FourBitModeStrategy : public ModeStrategy {
    public:
        void InitMode() override {
            this->lcd_->Reset();
            this->lcd_->SendCommand(LCD_CMD_4_BIT_MODE);
        }

        void SendCommandPart(uint8_t &command_id) override {
            this->lcd_->SendHigherNibble(command_id);
            this->lcd_->SendCmdSignals();
            command_id <<= 4;
        }

        void SendDataPart(uint8_t &data) override {
            this->lcd_->SendHigherNibble(data);
            this->lcd_->SendDataSignals();
            data <<= 4;
        }
    };

    class EightBitModeStrategy : public ModeStrategy {
    public:
        void InitMode() override {
            this->lcd_->SendCommand(LCD_CMD_8_BIT_MODE);
        }

        void SendCommandPart(uint8_t &command_id) override {
            this->lcd_->SendLowerNibble(command_id);
        }

        void SendDataPart(uint8_t &data) override {
            this->lcd_->SendLowerNibble(data);
        }
    };

    friend FourBitModeStrategy;

public:
    enum Mode {
        Mode4bit,
        Mode8bit,
    };

    explicit Lcd(ModeStrategy *mode_strategy) : mode_strategy(mode_strategy) {
        // Bidirectional reference.
        this->mode_strategy->InitLcdPtr(this);
    }

public:
    void Init() {
        this->mode_strategy->InitMode();
    }

    void SendCommand(uint8_t command_id) {
        this->mode_strategy->SendCommandPart(command_id);

        this->SendHigherNibble(command_id);
        this->SendCmdSignals();
    }


    void SendData(uint8_t data) {
        this->mode_strategy->SendDataPart(data);

        this->SendHigherNibble(data);
        this->SendDataSignals();
    }

private:

    void BusyCheck() {
        // ...

        this->mode_strategy->BusyCheck();

        // ...
    }

    void Reset();

    void SendHigherNibble(uint8_t val);

    void SendLowerNibble(uint8_t val);

    void SendCmdSignals();

    void SendDataSignals();

private:
    ModeStrategy *mode_strategy = nullptr;
};
```

But as I said there is a bidirectional reference.
How to solve it?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You might want to learn about `protected` as well as `private` and public. Derivative classes can access `protected` functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Avoid polymorphism in this case

You can avoid the circular reference by passing `Lcd *` to every member function of `ModeStrategy`, so the latter doesn't have to store that pointer. However,
given the code you have posted, I don't think using polymorphism is a good idea at all in this case. It involves pointer dereferencing and indirect function calls, when all you need is a few `if (mode == ...)`.

## Try to minimize the number of functions that need to know the `mode`

Perhaps you can just have a single function that takes care of sending a full byte, whether it's a command or data byte? For example:

```
void SendByte(uint8_t data, bool command) {
     if (mode == Mode8bit) {
         // write data
         // write command or data signals
     } else {
         // write data
         // write command or data signals
         // write data << 4
         // write command or data signals
     }  
}
```

Then `SendCommand()` and `SendData()` and even `Init()` can call `SendByte()` without having to know the mode.

## Unnecessary use of `this->`

You almost never need to explicitly write `this->` in C++. You are not even doing it consistently anyway, for example in `Init()` in the non-polymorphic version you call `SendCommand()` without `this->`.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the existing review, a few other points may be helpful to you.

### Rethink the interface

Chances are high that your software can't magically create hardware.  In other words, you probably want an instance of your `LCD` class to access one particular LCD.  Therefore you are unlikely to want copy or move constructors, so I would suggest they should be `delete`d.  Further, there's unlikely to be much use in having a separate `BusyCheck` -- if I were using the code, I'd want the `LCD` class constructor to be tied to a particular physical LCD and to have functions that print to the LCD.  I would expect the class itself to take care of initialization within the constructor and to manage contention.

### Think about testing

You *do* test your code, right?  One thing I've used for this is to create a virtual base object with all of the necessary methods, and then derive from that to create the actual object that write to the physical device.  During test, I might prefer to have a simulated device, so I create a separate derived object for that purpose.  All of the interfaces and interactions remain the same, but it gives you a way to test even in the absence of physical hardware.

### Consider initialization and thread safety

Most embedded systems I work with these days are multithreaded.  Your system may or may not be, but it's still good to think about.  Consider a handheld device in which the top line shows GPS coordinates and time (from a GPS object running in its own thread) and a battery object showing the state of charge (from a Battery object running in a different thread).  Both need asynchronous access to the LCD.